# How do I use Python's PIL library to get EXIF data from a photo starting with a hyperlink to the photo?

Tags: python, hyperlink, exif

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS


def get_exif(fn):
    ret = {}
    i = Image.open(fn)
    info = i._getexif()
    for tag, value in info.items():
        decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
        ret[decoded] = value
return ret
```

## links.csv is a file that contains all the hyperlinks to the photos

```
for line in open("links.csv"):
    print get_exif(requests.get(line))
```

## the above print statement causes an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accurately assess your problem more information is usually needed. For example the exact error and traceback.

First you should try running `get_exif` on a url from `links.csv` manually. If it fails the problem is in `get_exif`. If not it is in the `requests.get`.

*but*

Fortunately I have a guess as to what might be the issue. When you iterate using `for line in file` each line will end in a newline. Try using `requests.get(line.rstrip())` and see what happens.